# Sending to socket while server is disconected

Tags: c++, linux

I'm using function below in order

```
int sendData(int const Socket, unsigned char const * const Data, size_t const Length)
{
    return send(Socket, Data, Length, 0);
}
```

Function returns send bytes count.

If I disconnect server this function returns send bytes count equals to `Length`. Looks that system don't know other side is disconnected.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: my guess your connection is `TCP`. sadly, in `TCP` you may not be able to detect disconnections perfectly.

Comment: According to [The Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send), by always setting the flags to `0` you have simple re-implemented the `write()` function

Answer (score 2):

Sending data over sockets is a low level operation. A successful send is no guarantee that there will be a successful receive at the other end.

[The Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send) says:

> No indication of failure to deliver is implicit in a send()

So the server will have to send back an acknowledgement for the client to be sure.

As a side note, your function is simply recreating the system `write` function. According to [The Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/send):

> The only difference between send() and write(2) is the presence of flags. With a zero flags argument, send() is equivalent to write(2).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your connection is `TCP`.

Normally `send()` method detects closed connection and returns -1. But sadly, you cannot detect broken connection all the time (I read that it is possible that disconnected connection is not cause up to 30 mins).

The best approach is to send [heartbeats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(computing)) in your connection. If you don't get any heartbeat, it means that connection(or target service) is down. Then you can close socket and send data after reconnecting it.

Comment: Heartbeats are definitely not required for TCP being kept open or close detected (else the whole of the internet would be in trouble!).  They're usually just used to report that the application is alive and responsive, rather than hanging or struggling under load.

Comment: A heartbeat might tell you when you need to reconnect, but it would not tell you that a specific message had arrived (other than the heartbeat message).

Answer (score 0):

To detect if there's a connection failure, rather than depend on your write (as Galik says, is unreliable), use [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

On error, it returns a -1, and sets errno accordingly.

On a graceful disconnect, it will return 0 instead.

As an extra, one can use [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) on the socket to establish when it's state has changed

Comment: `select` alone can't tell you whether a socket has been disconnected or not, only whether it is readable or writable. You still have to perform an actual read to determine if the socket is still connected.

Comment: @RemyLebeau fixed

Answer (score 0):

That is a common problem for all *writing* system calls on a Unix-Linux system. The function shall return successfully as soon as the request has been queued. And that is true for disk writes too.

If an error occurs in the actual operation (disconnected sockect, or disk error), it may be reported on a different access, and at least on the `close`: that is the reason why `close` may report various errors.

So there is nothing more to expect: you cannot be sure that a `send` of `write` has reached its destination until you read (for a socket) or flush (for a file) on same handle (or of course close it).